# Windows Store apps fileopen picker

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I want to custom the fileopen picker. For example the user only allow to access to the particular folder only instead the user can choose anywhere it want. How do I do that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can't at the picker level. The `FileOpenPicker` is one of the few core APIs that limit user's access to the file system and it doesn't provide customization other than the APIs exposed by the class - like the [suggested location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.suggestedstartlocation.aspx) - but that is only the 'suggested' location and it gives you only a few built-in locations.

You could create your own app that [implements the File Open Picker contrac](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465174.aspx)t and perhaps it could be the same app that is going to use it, but there is no guarantee that the user will use this particular implementation of the `FileOpenPicker` and they can use the default one from the OS shell that gives them access to just about anything.